# Trouble decrypting using PostgreSQL's gnupg extension

Tags: php, postgresql, encryption, public-key-encryption, gnupg

I'm getting an error when I try to decrypt using PostgreSQL's gnupg extension and the gpg_pub_decrypt function.

Here's the query I'm executing, which should do a round-trip encryption/decryption of the string `Hello world!`:

```
select pgp_pub_decrypt(
           pgp_pub_encrypt('Hello world!', dearmor(:public_key)),
           dearmor(:private_key),
           ''
           );
```

Instead, I get the error:

```
'SQLSTATE[39000]: External routine invocation exception: 7 ERROR:  Corrupt data'
```

I execute the query and provide the public and private key values through this php script.

```
<?php

function roundTrip() {

  $pubkey = file_get_contents("public_key");
  $privkey = file_get_contents("secret_key");

  $conn = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=*********", "*********", "*********");
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $sql = "select pgp_pub_decrypt( pgp_pub_encrypt('Hello world!', dearmor(:public_key)), dearmor(:private_key), '')";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam(':public_key', $pubkey);
  $stmt->bindParam(':private_key', $privkey);
  $stmt->execute();             // <------------------ Error encountered here
  $row = $stmt->fetch();
  file_put_contents('test.out', $row[0]);
}

roundTrip();

?>
```

I generated the key pair with gnupg and it is not password protected, so the last argument to `pgp_pub_decrypt` is the empty string.

I've exported both private and public keys to ASCII files for the script to read.  They are included below for anyone who wants to verify their validity.

I can make a successful round trip using gpg on the command line using the unexported keys, so I know they work.  I'd use the exported ones if gpg provided a way to do so, but I don't think it does.

Can anybody tell me what's going wrong?

```
[mike@M5 ~]$ cat public_key
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.11 (GNU/Linux)
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=aUlA
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
[mike@M5 ~]$ cat secret_key
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.11 (GNU/Linux)
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=igkq
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
[mike@M5 ~]$
```

Comment: Since you have officially exposed your private key, I would strongly suggest you regenerate the key pair now.

Comment: @Mike This key pair will not be used to secure anything more sensitive than "Hello world", but thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [here](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/pgcrypto-pgp-pub-decrypt-with-passphrase-broken-td4359729.html), there is a bug in that when you provide a password it fails. Try doing:

```
pgp_pub_decrypt( pgp_pub_encrypt( 'Hello world', dearmor(:public_key) ), 
             dearmor(:private_key) ) `
```

and do not provide the third field in the `pgp_pub_decrypt` function.

Comment: The bug you linked to is certainly relevant, so I'm accepting your answer.  Turns out though that having an empty string as the third arg is okay.  The real problem was that when I edited my gpg key to remove the password I had originally set, I'd neglected to re-export the secret key.  So my program was still trying to use the key with password protection.